# Android Mobile Vision API and NN API

Tags: android, machine-learning, googleio

In Google I/O 2017, it introduced lots of technologies benefit to develop AI applications.

But I'm kind of confused to Mobile Vision API and NN API.

Any relationship between them ? 
Mobile vision API was built on top of NN(Neural Network) API ? Or they're just two independent APIs ?  The NN API will be only called by Tensorflow lite and application will just face to TF-lite.

Comment: Could you please tell me Mobile Vision API  uses which algorithm/techniques for face detection? I could not find any information about this.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Vision API is part of Google Play Services, so it is Android only.

The TF-Lite library is cross platform and presents the same API on both Android and iOS. When running TF-Lite on Android, the library uses the Android Neural Network API and system level runtime to take advantage of hardware acceleration.